# Close main window after opening a new one

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I found this example of code here on stackoverflow and I would like to make the first window close when a new one is opened.
So what I would like is when a new window is opened, the main one should be closed automatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk

from Tkinter import *

class windowclass():

        def __init__(self,master):
                self.master = master
                self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
                self.lbl = Label(master , text = "Label")
                self.lbl.pack()
                self.btn = Button(master , text = "Button" , command = self.command )
                self.btn.pack()
                self.frame.pack()

        def command(self):
                print 'Button is pressed!'

                self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
                self.app = windowclass1(self.newWindow)

class windowclass1():

        def __init__(self , master):
                self.master = master
                self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
                master.title("a")
                self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25 , command = self.close_window)
                self.quitButton.pack()
                self.frame.pack()


        def close_window(self):
                self.master.destroy()


root = Tk()

root.title("window")

root.geometry("350x50")

cls = windowclass(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would withdraw the main window, but you have no way to close the program after the button click in the Toplevel, when the main window is still open but doesn't show  Also pick one or the other of (but don't use both)

```
import Tkinter as tk

from Tkinter import *
```

This opens a 2nd Toplevel which allows you to exit the program

```
import Tkinter as tk

class windowclass():

        def __init__(self,master):
                self.master = master
                ##self.frame = tk.Frame(master)  not used
                self.lbl = tk.Label(master , text = "Label")
                self.lbl.pack()
                self.btn = tk.Button(master , text = "Button" , command = self.command )
                self.btn.pack()
                ##self.frame.pack()  not used

        def command(self):
                print 'Button is pressed!'

                self.master.withdraw()
                toplevel=tk.Toplevel(self.master)
                tk.Button(toplevel, text="Exit the program",
                          command=self.master.quit).pack()
                self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
                self.app = windowclass1(self.newWindow)

class windowclass1():

        def __init__(self , master):
                """ note that "master" here refers to the TopLevel
                """
                self.master = master
                self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
                master.title("a")
                self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame,
                                  text = 'Quit this TopLevel',
                                  width = 25 , command = self.close_window)
                self.quitButton.pack()
                self.frame.pack()

        def close_window(self):
                self.master.destroy()  ## closes this TopLevel only

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("window")

root.geometry("350x50")

cls = windowclass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe close is not right word, but maybe hide it? and then have possibility to show it again?

Comment: That would require something like a button which would deiconify the master window, like the exit button in the example above. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
```

You are not creating a new window independent completely from your root (or `master`) but rather a child of the Toplevel (`master` in your case), of course this new `child` toplevel will act independent of the `master` until the `master` gets detroyed where the `child` toplevel will be destroyed as well,

To make it completely seperate, create a new instance of the Tk object and have it close the `windowclass` window (destroy its object):

```
self.newWindow = Tk()
```

you have two options here:

1 - Either you need to specify in the `windowclass1.close_window()`, that you want to destroy the `cls` object when you create the `windowclass1()` object, this way:

```
def close_window(self):
                cls.master.destroy()
```

2 - Which is the preferred one for generality, is to destroy the `cls` after you create `windowclass1` object in the `windowclass.command()` method, like this:

```
def command(self):
                print 'Button is pressed!'
                self.newWindow = Tk()
                self.app = windowclass1(self.newWindow)
                self.master.destroy()
```

and make the quitButton in the `__init__()` of windowclass1 like this:

```
 self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.master.quit)
```

to quit completely your program